# Uniqueness theorem of harmonic function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in R^{2} |y>0\}$. If $u(x,y)=xy$, then $u$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$.  But the constant function $0$ is also harmonic with the same boundary condition.  How do we show that this does not contradict the uniqueness theorem of harmonic function.

Comment: Can you state the version of the uniqueness theorem?

Comment: Uniqueness holds within some class of functions. You probably need some condition at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of uniqueness of solution depends on Maximum principle.

The maximum principle has assumption bounded domain.

As in your problem domain is Upper half-plane , so uniqueness theorem will not hold.